# Editing realm object relationship without committing transaction

Tags: android, realm

I have a class called Person one of the variables is a realm list called clothes:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject{
  private RealmList<Clothing> clothes;
}
```

Clothes is used to display in a RecyclerView wherein the contents can be edited such as quantity, color of clothing, or cloth type.

When I edit the clothing values:

```
public void setCloth(int i, Cloth cloth) {
        realmInstance.beginTransaction();
        clothes.set(i, cloth);
        realmInstance.commitTransaction();
    }
```

Of course, the record is saved. My problem is what if the user, cancels the editing of the WHOLE Person object. Then the clothes list change will persist.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you would be a great fan of nested transactions (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1509).

In the next release of Realm, a new method `copyFromRealm()` will be introduced. You should copy the `clothes` list and use `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` when you commit the `Person` object.

Comment: Hi giesshirt, nice to know that realm's staff is active. 

While the link you posted is spot on and is definitely a welcome change, I've already solved the problem, let me post it.

Comment: Please post any working solution - it might be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved the issue:

The solution is if you're using a fragment or an activity, and displaying the realm object and it's relationship through widgets, begin transaction immediately.

```
Realm realmInstance = Realm.getInstance(this);
realmInstance.beginTransaction();
```

This way, changes done directly on the realm object whether a relationship or a plain variable will be allowed.

To cancel the changes done simply use:

```
realmInstance.cancelTransaction();
```

This code can be invoked by overriding onBackPressed or any means of canceling the editing.

After canceling the transaction, any changes done including the RealmList objects will be forfeited.

More Info:
I was displaying the clothes list array in a recyleview through an adapter with editing controls (etc. setting the qty, changing cloth type). This solution can also be used in that scenario.

Hope this helps.